# How to pass the variables from my quotes in to the signature code

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to pass the quotes variable $quote to the signature place but it seems not work.
not show my text after my post like i need and i can not fin any way yet to pass 
the quotes variable to the signature code.
I have try different ways to get pass the quotes array in to the signature code I not get any error but nothing happen

This is my code

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Random Text Quotes
Version: 1.0
Description: Random Text Quotes Albert Einstein.
Plugin URI: https://mediaads.eu/
 Author: Helder Ventura
 Author URI: https://mediaads.eu
 Version: (standalone)
 Usage: install activate and done
 */
 $bgcolor = '#FFFFCC';
 $textcolor = 'black';
$textsize = '2';
// Array Structure:  "Quote","Author"
$allqts = array
("*His aim was to substitute for a petrified and barren
system of ideas the unbiased and strenuous quest
for a deeper and more consistent comprehension of
physical and astronomical facts.", 
    "Albert Einstein",
"The discovery and use of scientific reasoning by
Galileo was one of the most important achievements
in the history of human thought.<br>" ,
    "Albert Einstein",
"I admire Gandhi greatly but I believe there are two
weaknesses in his program.",
    "Albert Einstein",
"I believe that Gandhi’s views were the most enlightened
among all of the political men of our time.",
    "Albert Einstein",
"Liberty, when it begins to take root, is a plant of rapid growth.", 
    "George Washington",
"Gandhi, the greatest political genius of our time,
indicated the path to be taken.",
    "Albert Einstein",
"Gandhi’s development resulted from extraordinary
intellectual and moral forces in combination with
political ingenuity and a unique situation.",
    "Albert Einstein",
"Anyone who has never made a mistake has never tried anything new",
    "Albert Einstein",
"Progress doesn't come from early risers, progress is made<br>by lazy men 
looking for easier ways to do things.",
    "Lazarus Long <font size=-2>(Time Enough for Love by Robert A. Heinlein)
</font>",
"On Johann Wolfgang von Goethe (1749–1832)
I feel in him a certain condescending attitude toward
the reader, and miss the humility that is comforting,
especially when it comes from great men.",
    "Albert Einstein",
"*This was the first time I’ve ever heard of such
an important man who speaks at least briefly with
his mother every day.",
    "Albert Einstein",
"On Werner Heisenberg (1901–1976)
Professor Heisenberg was here, a German.",
    "Albert Einstein",
"I am very happy here and enjoying the American
summer as well as the news about Hitler’s mad
deed of desperation.",
    "Albert Einstein",
"Hitler appeared, a man with limited intellectual
abilities and unfit for any useful work, bursting with
envy and bitterness against all whom circumstance
and nature had favored over him. . . .",
    "Albert Einstein",
"*I haven’t forgotten that the Swiss authorities didn’t
stand by me in any way when Hitler stole all of my
savings, even those designated for my children.",
    "Albert Einstein",
"On Immanuel Kant (1724–1804)
*Kant’s much-praised view on Time reminds me of
Andersen’s tale of the emperor’s new clothes, only
that instead of the emperor’s new clothes we have
the form of intuition.",
    "Albert Einstein",
"*Kant is sort of a highway with lots and lots of milestones.
Then all the little dogs come and each deposits
his contribution at the milestones.",
    "Albert Einstein",
"What seems to me the most important thing in
 Kant’s philosophy is that it speaks of a priori concepts
 for the construction of science.",
    "Albert Einstein",
 "Kant, thoroughly convinced of the indispensability
 of certain concepts, took them—just as they are selected—to
 be the necessary premises for every kind
 of thinking and differentiated them from concepts
 of empirical origin.",
    "Albert Einstein",
"On George Kennan (1904–2005)
Princeton University Press sent me George Kennan’s
new book [Realities of American Foreign Policy] and I
read it right away.",
        "Albert Einstein",
"[Kepler] belonged to those few who cannot do otherwise
than openly acknowledge their convictions
on every subject. . . .",
    "Albert Einstein",
"There we meet a finely sensitive person, passionately
dedicated to the search for a deeper insight into the
essence of natural events, who, despite internal and
external difficulties, reached his loftily placed goal.",
    "Albert Einstein",
    "Share Your Love With The World.",
    "Helder Ventura"
    );

  // Gets the Total number of Items in the array
  //  Divides by 2 because there is a Quote followed by an Author
 $totalqts = (count($allqts)/2);

 // Subtracted 1 from the total because '0' is not accounted for otherwise
 $nmbr = (rand(0,($totalqts-1)));
 $nmbr = $nmbr*2;

//$nmbr = 18;

$quote = $allqts[$nmbr];
     $nmbr = $nmbr+1;
$author = $allqts[$nmbr];

// You can delete this section
//   it is only so Search engines can find it
if ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == "/quotes.php") {
echo "<Title>Random Text Quote</title>";
echo "<meta name=\"Description\" content=\"Random Text Quote\">";
echo "<meta name=\"keywords\" content=\"Random Text Quote\">";
}
/// End Delete


$space = "<font color=$bgcolor>.....................................</font>";
$comments = "<br><center><font size='-2'><i><a href='quotes.php'>Random Text 
Quote</a></i></font></center>";

echo "<center>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<Font color=$textcolor size='$textsize'><i>";
echo "$quote<br>";
echo "</i></font>";
echo "$space $author";
echo "$comments";
echo "</center>";
// You can delete this section as well - it's my shameless plug:
//   it is only so Search engines can find it
if ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == "/quotes.php") {
    echo "<br/><br/>If you <i>really</i> like it, I do accept donations via 
PayPal: <a href='http://zonadelike.publiadds.org.pt//donate'>Donations</a>";
echo "<br/><br/>";
}
/// End Delete


IF ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == "/quotes.php") {
show_source("quotes.php");
}
// Add Signature Image after single post
add_filter('the_content','add_signature', 1);
function add_signature($text) {
global $post;
if(($post->post_type == 'post')) 
$text .= '<div class="signature"><a href="https://mediaads.eu/" 
target="_blank" title=$text>'.$quote.'</a></div>';


return $text;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing $quote in function.
your function should be like

```
function add_signature($text,$quote) {
global $post;
if(($post->post_type == 'post')) 
$text .= '<div class="signature"><a href="https://mediaads.eu/" 
target="_blank" title=$text>'.$quote.'</a></div>';
return $text;
}
```

Well i have try to do with your code but i can not solve the problem to show my array quotes in to the signature place, So i have try to do in a different way i have use this code:

I continue to not this problem resolve because i can not get it work properly I have try a different code but i continue to not get the quotes apear after my content i have try with this function but how can i add my quotes in to the content place, i mean the array quotes code

```
function text_after_content($content) { 
if(!is_feed() && !is_home()) { 
$content.= "content quotes variable";
$content.= "<p>Don’t forget to check them at 
<a href='mediaads.eu'>Media Ads</a></p>"; } 
return $content; } 
add_filter ('the_content', 'text_after_content'); ?>
```